# Find and replace regular expression with alternate format

Tags: regex, sed, grep, find

I have a file that has lines that contain text like this

```
something,12:3456789,somethingelse
foobar,12:345678,somethingdifferent
```

For lines where the second item in the line has 6 digits after the `:` I would like to alternate the format of it by adding a 0 in the front and shifting the `:`. For example the above would change to:

```
something,12:3456789,somethingelse
foobar,01:2345678,somethingdifferent
```

I can't figure out how to do this using sed or any unix command line tool

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to match the middle section where you have 2 digits followed by `:` followed by *exactly* 6 digits. If you capture the text in individual groups appropriately you can move them around in your result. Note the `\b` word boundary at the end of the pattern is to ensure that we match on exactly 6 digits and don't match on lines which have the full 7 digits:

```
/\b(\d)(\d):(\d{6})\b/0\1:\2\3/
 |__________________| |______|
       pattern       replacement
```

This gives the expected output. You can experiment with it online [here](https://regex101.com/r/QdyXNI/1)

---

`sed` doesn't have Perl style specifiers such as `\d`. Instead, you will need to use `[[:digit:]]`. Here is the updated regex that works with `sed`

```
sed -E 's/\b([[:digit:]])([[:digit:]]):([[:digit:]]{6})\b/0\1:\2\3/g' myfile.txt
```

As @Jonathan Leffler pointed out, `\b` doesn't work on Mac's `sed` so you will instead need to add commas in your regex pattern at the front and back and then replace them back in the replacement pattern

Comment: I'm running this command but it won't do anything on mac sed. `sed -i -E 's/,\(\d\)\(\d\):\(\d{6}\),/\|0\1:\2\3\|/' myfile.txt`

Comment: @Anthony: The `-i` option in Mac `sed` requires a non-empty argument, so it uses `-E` as the backup suffix — which in turn means that you aren't using extended regular expressions.  If you want to edit in place (dangerous until the code is known to work), then `-i ''` (an empty string as the backup suffix) is necessary.  If the script must travel between Mac and Linux, then you need a non-empty suffix attached to the `-i` option: `-i.bak`.

Comment: The Mac `sed` doesn't recognize `\b`, so given that the field is surrounded by commas, you need to use `sed -E 's/,([[:digit:]])([[:digit:]]):([[:digit:]]{6}),/,0\1:\2\3,/g'` — this changes the data on a Mac, and should work the same on Linux etc.

Comment: The OP said "For lines where the second item in the line has 6 digits after the :...", this solution may give a false positive if the second item does not meet the above criteria but another does. The regexp should anchor the match to the second item i.e. `/^[^,]*,second_item,/`